# FileChooser and Scanner

Tags: java

```
    JFileChooser jfch = new JFileChooser();
            jfch.showOpenDialog(null);
            File f = jfch.getSelectedFile();

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


            try {
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
                while (sc.hasNext()) {
                    sb.append(sc.next());
                }
                sc.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MainWindow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }      

            System.out.print(sb.toString());
}
```

What's wrong with it? I choose file that contains some text for sure but still get's variable sb empty :/

Comment: What is not working? Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Put some logging or System.out after each line and analyse what is happening. For example, after you assign File f = .. do some logging if the variable 'f' is good.

Put a System.out in the while loop and before that.

This will give you some visibility on whats happening, or learn how to use a debugger breakpoints etc to analyze your code at run time.